# Associating strings as metadata with controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to add some meta data to some rectangles I have created in a wpf application that is associated with each rectangle.

Like I have a string associated with each rectangle.

I have been putting this string in the tooltip so I can access it in code associated with the rectangle,  but obviously there's a better solution to this, I'm just not sure what it is.

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Tag property for that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx